# Prop is undefined when using vue router with query params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue-router v.3.3.4 and I want to pass some value from one component to another with query.

I followed VueJS documentation on https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode and here is an excerpt of my code

From my Register.vue component, I call the router to go to the Login.vue component by passing a `success` value

```js
this.$router.push({path: '/login', query: { success: 'true' }});
```

In my router definition, I define the corresponding route as follows:

```js
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/Login.vue'),
    props: (route) => ({ success: route.query.success }),
  },
```

Finally, in my Login.vue component, I want to use this prop to display a message if the value is `true`, so I define the props object for my component as follows:

```js
props: {
    success: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    }
  },
```

The URL is correctly set up like `/login?success=true` but the `success` props is `undefined`.
I also tried with a Boolean type instead of string but with no success.

I have found many similar issues but most of them were due to either an old version of vue-router, or a wrong definition of the route in router.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: where you get `success` props is `undefined` ? can you provide more information?

Comment: @MohammadMasoudi Actually, it doesn't render if I try to bind the prop to some part of the template using {{success}} or within a sub-component. And if I try to inspect the value in the created method (where I want to use it to update a component's data element) by printing it in the console, I get undefined.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/route-props-in-vue-2-6o1gq?file=/src/views/Login.vue).

Comment: @tony19 thank you for this example. Yet, I can't find what is the difference with my own code. If I look into the Vue DevTools console, I do have an `$attrs` with `success: "true"`. Do you have any idea where things can go wrong or how I could further investigate the problem ?

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

try this it's will work

```
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/Login.vue'),
    props: true
}
```

Comment: Actually, the `success` prop is still `undefined` if I try your solution. Also, if I look at the official documentation, the Boolean mode that you suggest is related to the `route.params` but I don't get any parameters in my url path.